# Paginator zend framework warning

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-paginator

> Warning: No view partial provided and
>   no default set in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/getv/library/Zend/Paginator.php
>   on line 465

This is the warning message that I get when loading the paginator; can someone give me a solution or tips where my problem could be?

```
public function getPaginator() {
    if ($this->view === null) {
        $this->view = $this->getActionController()->view;
    }

   $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    /* @var $searcher ZendX_Searcher_Abstract */
    foreach ($this->searchers as $searcher) {
        $searcher->setRequest($this->getRequest())
                ->setView($this->view)
                ->setSelect($this->select)
                ->perform();
    }

    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($this->select));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->getRequest()->getParam('page', 1));
    $paginator->setPageRange(7);

    if ($this->perPage > 0) {
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($this->perPage);
    } else {
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(PHP_INT_MAX);
    }

    return $paginator;
}
```

Comment: i think you need: `Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial ( 'paginator.phtml' ); `

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was getting the same problem. I am using zend pagination view helper. The solution I got is little strange. In the view(.phtml) file I was checking like

```
if(isset($this->records) && $this->records!='')
```

but later than i change this to

```
if(isset($this->records) && sizeof($this->records) > 0)
```

and my problem solved. Hope, it may be helpful to you and others.

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution is IMO what RobertPitt proposes:

```
Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial ('paginator.phtml' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is not triggered from your controller but rather, from your view.

Show the script where you call `<?php echo $this->paginationControl(...) ?>`

For reference, you need to supply at least two things to the `PaginationControl` view helper:

1. A `Zend_Paginator` object. Supplied as the first argument to the helper or by setting it as the `paginator` property of your view.
2. A partial view path. Supplied as the third argument to the view helper (after `scrollingStyle`) or via the static method RobertPitt mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I don't give to view an empty paginator object but an empty string, this to avoid an initial not filtered search.
I solved in this way in my view.phtml:

```
if ( is_a($this->paginator,'Zend\Paginator\Paginator') ) {
  // paginator print
}
```

I hope this help.